# How to read in a double from a char16_t string literal?

Tags: c++, char

How can I read in a double from a char16_t string (char16_t *) using nothing but standard C++11 features?

I tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

double char16_to_double( const char16_t* s )
{
  double n = 0;
  std::basic_stringstream<char16_t> ss( s );
  ss >> n;
  return n;
}

int main()
{
  try {
    double n = char16_to_double( u"0.1" );
    std::cout << "Value of n: " << n << std::endl;
  } catch( ... ) {
    std::cout << "Exception!" << std::endl;   
  }
  return 0;
}
```

However it throws an exception in https://cpp.sh, or results in 0, not 0.1, when I compile it with g++-7. What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Note: `assert(ss >> n);` fails, so there is no conversion performed at all.

Comment: That's what I saw in gdb as well. But how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution I found is converting the char16_t (which is UTF16 encoded) to a char string via `std::wstring_convert`:

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

double char16_to_double( const char16_t* s )
{
  std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t > my_conv;
  double n = 0;
  std::istringstream ss( my_conv.to_bytes( s ).c_str() );
  ss >> n;
  return n;
}

int main()
{
  try {
    double n = char16_to_double( u"0.1" );
    std::cout << "Value of n: " << n << std::endl;
  } catch( ... ) {
    std::cout << "Exception!" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

If anyone has a more straightforward solution, I'll be open for it.

Answer (score 0):

you can just cast transform it to a string and use **stod** from stdlib.h

```
double char16_to_double( const char16_t* s ) {

     std::string str = "";

     for(size_t i = 0; s[i] != 0; i++) {
          str += s[i];
      }

      return stod(str);
}
```

Comment: here you are, after a little more search, i think this the simplest way i found.
@Arne

Comment: `sizeof(s)/sizeof(*s)` is a common idiom for finding the size of an array, but here there is no array, just a pointer, so that value isn't particularly useful. If you need the number of elements in the array you have to pass it as an argument. If the array is known to be null terminated you can check for the terminator. The loop would be `for (size_t i = 0; s[i] != 0; i++)`.

Comment: i think "const char16_t* s" is a const pointer to array of **char16_t**s here, so i used that common idiom, but for sure your suggestion is more optimized.

Comment: It's a pointer to `char16_t`; it doesn't matter whether the location it points to is a single object of type `char16_t` or an array. It's just a pointer, and you can't get the number of objects that it points at without more information. Print out the value that this gives you, and call the function with arrays of varying lengths; you'll see that the value is always the same.

Comment: your point are clear here, and when i run my code and tested it against some long values worked fine, that's why i posted here, but i think it worthy to edit the code and mention your solution, thanks